# Flexbox add X and Y scrollbars to children but not body

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, overflow

I'm trying to get a a layout where I have a main header, a sidebar, the main content, and a main content header, where the only scroll bars are in vertical direction for the sidebar and the vertical and horizontal directions of the main content.

In my current code, I am only able to get a vertical scroll bar on the body and a horizontal scroll bar on the content, and it is hard to access because the scroll bar for the content is at the very bottom of the body, which I don't want to grow in height.

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to make the body fit to width and height of the screen, while the contents of `#menu_bar` and `#main_content` have the correct scroll bars.

Here is a mock up of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is what I have right now.

```css
body {
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu_bar {
  position: relative;
  border-top: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#tabs {
  width: 100%;
}

.tab {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main_header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#main_content {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.vertical-divider {
  border-left: black solid 1px;
}

.horizontal-divider {
  border-top: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <header>
    PAGE HEADER
  </header>
  <div class="horizontal-divider" id="header_content_divider"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="vertical-divider hidden" style="display: none;"></div>
    <!-- Left Menu Bar -->
    <div id="menu_bar">
      <div id="tabs">
        <div class="tab">Tab 0</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 4</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 5</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 6</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 7</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 8</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 9</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 10</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 11</div>
        <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
        <div class="tab">Tab 12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-divider" id="left_main_divider"></div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="main_header">
        MAIN HEADER
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
      <div id="main_content">
        <div id="wide">
          ThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContent
        </div>
        <div id="tall">
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
          <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this layout work you need to be familiar with at least five CSS concepts.

I'll post the code first, with the explanations at the end.

### Code

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* will help with triggering overflow 
                             (by allowing use of flex properties further in) */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0; /* override default margins */
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;   
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content {
  display: flex; /* children line up in a row */
  height: 50vh;  /* hard limi t help trigger overflow condition, 
                    while leaving plenty of space for the header */
  flex-grow: 1;  /* consume remaining height */
}

#menu_bar {
  height: 100%;  /* inherit parent height; essential for overflow to trigger */
  flex: 0 1 300px; /* space for tabs; max-width taken from individual tabs rule */
}

#tabs {
  overflow: auto; /* first scrollbar requirement met */
  height: 100%;  /* inherit parent height; essential for overflow to trigger */
  background-color: lightgreen; /* demo */
}

.tab {
  padding: 10px;
  /* max-width: 300px; */ /* rule moved to container */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


#main {
  flex: 1; /* consume all space (so box width not dependent on content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 0; /* override flex minimum width setting */
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#main_header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#main_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; /* can shrink to fit (flex-shrink: 1 default) */
  overflow: auto; /* second scrollbar requirement set */
  background-color: orange;
}

#wide {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>PAGE HEADER</header>
<div id="content">
  <div id="menu_bar">
    <div id="tabs">
      <div class="tab">Tab 0</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 4</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 5</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 6</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 7</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 8</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 9</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 10</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 11</div>
      <div class="tab">Tab 12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="main_header">MAIN HEADER</div>
    <div id="main_content">
      <div id="wide">
    ThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContentThisIsWideContent
      </div>
      <div id="tall">
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
        <p>ThisIsTallContent</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cwhv5fem/)

---

### Explanations

As mentioned in the intro, there are multiple CSS concepts that need to be understood for this layout to work.

1. **The overflow property needs a hard limit**, so that it can actually overflow something. Without a fixed length, there's nothing to overflow.

   - [Set vertical scrollbar on flex children, not whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57747410/3597276)
   - [Grid with viewport height and inner scrolling div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54564976/3597276)
2. **Flex items have a minimum size equal to the size of the content**, which sometimes must be overridden for content to fit neatly in the viewport.

   - [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
3. **Flex items can shrink, by default.** This means you can set nested flex items to `height: 100%`, which can trigger and overflow without overflowing the container.

   - [Flex items are shrinking below flex-basis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48209955/3597276)
4. **The body element has a default margin set by the browser.** You can override this setting with `body { margin: 0 }` and eliminate an unnecessary vertical scrollbar.

   - [How wide is the default `<body>` margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13127887/3597276)
5. **You don't need to add dividers in the HTML.** It's a lot of extra and unnecessary code. Just use CSS borders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solves most of the issues, but two things are left. For `#main`, I want it to fill the whole width of the page even if `#main_content` isn't that wide. I tried adding `width: 100%`, but if the contents of `#main_content` is too wide, then elements I put at the end of the `#main_header` using `justify-content: flex-end` on a child will go off the screen, which I do not want (nor a scroll bar). Also, if the window is too small, `body` still has scroll bars.

Comment: Yeah, `width: 100%` won't do. Add `flex: 1` to `#main`. I'm not seeing the second problem. Code demos revised.